# Angular2 Update form value inside FormArray

Tags: angular, formarray

I need update 'lat' and 'lon' values inside FormArray:

```
initRows() {
        return this._fb.group({
            address: "",
            lat: 0,
            lon: 0,
        });
   }




 initForm() {
        this.searchForm = this._fb.group({
        addresses: this._fb.array([this.initRows()]),
    });
```

I need update them after callback:

```
 this.someService.getData().subscribe(
                  (response) => {this.data = response.json()
                                 this.lon = this.data.x;
                                 this.lat = this.data.y;
                                // UPDATE MY 'lat' and 'lon'
                  },
                  (error) => console.log('ERROR: ' + error)
          );
```

form.value object:

```
{

  "addresses": [
    {
      "address": {
        "text": "Weberweg, 58566, Kierspe, Nordrhein-Westfalen, DEU"
     },
      "lat": 0,
      "lon": 0
    },
     {
      "address": {
        "text": "Weberweg, 58566, Kierspe, Nordrhein-Westfalen, DEU"
     },
      "lat": 0,
      "lon": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

P.S. 'lat' and 'lon' not an inputs, just data

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure is it "right" way, but you can do this:

```
    /* getter for addresses.
    get addresses() {
       this.seachForm.controls.addresses as FormArray;
    }

    /* function for loading data */
    public loadData() {
        this.someService.getData().subscribe(
           (response) => {
                          this.data = response.json()
                          this.lon = this.data.x; // it is global lon like I understood
                          this.lat = this.data.y; // it is global lat like I understood
                          this.addresses.controls.forEach((address) => {
                                 address.get('lat').setValue(this.lat);
                                 address.get('lon').setValue(this.lon);
                          }),
           (error) => console.log('ERROR: ' + error)
      );
}
```

Hope I got you right and this answer is helpful for you.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying update these values after server responce and such kind of FormGroup can be several(dynamic add/remove fields). The main point to get current FormGroup control

Comment: Can I get not hole array, just current formGroup?